# Make a group of args into a variable in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

So, I have a Discord bot and thought of an idea to add a weather command to it. I got the part where the message is being sent in an embed to work, but to run the command I would have to run it with the city and state without spaces (`/weather SanFrancisco CA` is what it would look like). What I want to do is make it so that at least the command can have spaces like this: `/weather San Fransisco CA` or `/weather 'San Fransisco' CA`. Here is my code (I have taken out the unneeded parts).

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const bot = new Discord.Client()
const PREFIX = '/';
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
const ping = require('minecraft-server-util')
const weather = require('weather-js')
bot.on('message', message => {
  if (message.channel.type === 'dm') {return}
  let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(' ')
  if(message.content.startsWith(PREFIX))
  switch (args[0]) {
    case 'weather':
      weather.find({search: `${args[1]}, ${args[2]}`, degreeType: 'F'}, function(err, result) {
        if(err) console.log(err);
        var currentw = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setTitle(`Current Weather in ${args[1]} in state ${args[2]}`)
          .addField('Temperature', result[0].current.temperature)
          .addField('Sky Text', result[0].current.skytext)
          .addField('Humidity', result[0].current.humidity)
          .addField('Wind Speed & Direction', result[0].current.winddisplay)
          .addField('Feels Like', result[0].current.feelslike)
          .addField('Location', result[0].current.observationpoint)
          .addField('Time', result[0].current.observationtime)
          .addField('Date', result[0].current.date)
        message.channel.send(currentw)
      });
}})
  bot.login(TOKEN);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use quotes you can split the string like this:

```js
let foo = "\"San Francisco\" CA";
let args = foo.split("\"");

console.log(args);
```

This would return:
`[ '', 'San Francisco', ' CA' ]`

You can simply remove the first index by doing:

```js
args.splice(0, 1);
```

And that will return:
`[ 'San Francisco', ' CA' ]`

Edit: Fixed typo.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but I would like to be able to replace `"\"San Francisco\" CA"` with an arg passed in from a Discord message.

Comment: You can easily do that by turning the foo variables value into that argument. If you're confused about the ``\"`` that's just escaping the ``"`` and is just a regular ``"``.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's the most efficient way but if you split by the space you should be able to do a for loop to determine the args and put them all together in a string.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const bot = new Discord.Client()
const PREFIX = '/';
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
const ping = require('minecraft-server-util')
const weather = require('weather-js')
bot.on('message', message => {
  if (message.channel.type === 'dm') {return}
  let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(' ')
  if(message.content.startsWith(PREFIX))
  switch (args[0]) {
    case 'weather':
    let city;
    for (let i = 1; i < args.length - 1; i+= 1) {
      city += args[i];
    }
    weather.find({search: `city, ${args[args.length - 1]}`, degreeType: 'F'}, function(err, result) {
            if(err) console.log(err);
            var currentw = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
              .setTitle(`Current Weather in ${args[1]} in state ${args[2]}`)
              .addField('Temperature', result[0].current.temperature)
              .addField('Sky Text', result[0].current.skytext)
              .addField('Humidity', result[0].current.humidity)
              .addField('Wind Speed & Direction', result[0].current.winddisplay)
              .addField('Feels Like', result[0].current.feelslike)
              .addField('Location', result[0].current.observationpoint)
              .addField('Time', result[0].current.observationtime)
              .addField('Date', result[0].current.date)
            message.channel.send(currentw)
          });
    }})
      bot.login(TOKEN);
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. However, when I tried this code it crashes. (With the error of ```city is not defined```)